# Question about a compact Hausdorff countable topological space

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \tau) $ be a compact Hausdorff topological space. How can I prove that, if $X$ is countable, so $\{ x \in X : \{ x \}  \in \tau \} $ is dense in $(X, \tau)$?

Comment: use Baire Category Theorem?

Comment: @ForeverMozart which countable collection of dense open subsets of $X$ do I use? $ {x} \in \tau$ isn't dense, because it is closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose $A:=\{x\in X:\{x\}\in\tau\}$ is not dense.

Then $X\setminus \overline A$ is non-empty, countable, and locally compact Hausdorff.

By the Baire Category Theorem, $X\setminus \overline A$ has an isolated point, which is also an isolated point in $X$.

(BCT: If $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff, then $X$ is not the union of a countable number of closed nowhere dense sets.)

Comment: Are closed nowhere dense sets closed sets with empty interior?

Comment: @user435803 yes, you can prove that that is equivalent

Comment: We can also show, without Baire,  that a non-empty locally compact $T_2$ space with no isolated points has a subspace of cardinal at least $2^{\aleph_0}.$ We use a construction analogous to the making of the Cantor set. It is similar to proving that a non-empty complete metric space with no isolated points has a subspace homeomorphic to the Cantor set....... So  if $\bar A\ne X \ne \phi$ then $X$ \ $\bar A$ would be uncountable.... Good use of the Baire theorem here.